# to extract hindi,tamil,punjabi(Indian languages) post from a social networking site

Tags: python, cookies, beautifulsoup

i am using python and beautiful soup..trying to extract hindi,tamil,punjabi(Indian languages) post from a social networking site with the help of cookies..i am bale to extract but the extract is not in that language itself rather is in some encoded form ..i want it in the same language..eg:hindi post should be extracted the same in hindi only..

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
from html2text import html2text
import re
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(),  max_time=1)
urls = []

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1'),('Connection','keep-alive'),('Accept','application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'),('Accept-Encoding','gzip, deflate, sdch'),('Host','link'),('Referer','https://link/'),('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest'),('Accept-Language','en-US,en;q=0.8')]

br.open('https://link')

br._factory.is_html = True
# Select the first (index zero) form
#br.select_form(predicate=lambda f: f.attrs.get('id', None) == 'login_form')
br.select_form(nr=0)

# User credentials
br.form['USER'] = 'username'
br.form['PASSWORD'] = 'password'

# Login
br.submit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
for tag in soup.find_all("div", re.compile("classname")):
   #print tag
     for tag1 in tag.find_all(re.compile("^p")):
          print tag1
```

output sample:

\u0baa\u0b9f\u0bbf\u0ba4\u0bcd\u0ba4\u0ba4\u0bbf\u0bb2\u0bcd \u0baa\u0bbf\u0b9f\u0bbf\u0ba4\u0bcd\u0ba4\u0ba4\u0bc1 \u263a

expected output: written in that particular language(here tamil)

Comment: its still coming in encoded form only..no difference..@Vaulstein

Comment: expect an output of this sort...(same as the post in site)                        मुहाजिर है , मगर हम एक दुनिया छोड़ आये है , तुम्हरे पास जितना है हम उतना छोड़ आये है ।

Comment: have already tried that.. no difference in output @Vaulstein

Comment: @Vaulstein..it gives the html page..and wherever hindi or tamil text comes,it print in encoded form........ \u0ba4\u0ba4\u0bcd\u0ba4\u0bc1\u0bb5\u0bae\u0bcd \u0b9a\u0bca\u0bb2\u0bcd\u0bb2\u0bc1\u0bb1\u0ba4\u0bc1 \u0b8e\u0baa\u0bcd\u0baa\u0b9f\u0bbf?</a></h4><p>\u0ba4\u0ba4\u0bcd\u0ba4\u0bc1\‌​u0bb5\u0bae\u0bcd \u0b9a\u0bca\u0bb2\u0

Comment: @Vaulstein.. tried the solutions in that site..but none worked.. i just want to extract the hindi post in hindi(not in encoded form)..same for other languages...

Comment: how about `.decode('string_escape').decode('utf8')`?

Comment: I used   .decode('unicode-escape') ....this worked for me... and thanks @Vaulstein ..ur solution also works

Comment: Add it as the answer then 

Answer (score 0):

**unicode-escape** worked for me.

```
.decode('unicode-escape')
```